# How to exit from node script after a asynchronous operations completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run a loop and performing async operation in it. I am trying to delete documents from `Mongodb`. I want the script to terminate when all delete operations completed. I tried using `process.exit(0)`, but when I use this method to terminate the script, no number is getting deleted .

```
async function deletor() {
mobile_numbers.forEach(async (mobile_number) => {
    await db.collection(db_config.collectionName).remove(
    { mobile: mobile_number }
    )
})
}
deletor()
process.exit(0)
```

When all delete operations completed, then the script should terminate. but it terminates before the delete operation completes. I want to add this script to cron job, and I want to terminate the script when all the async operations are completed.

How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Node will do so automatically unless you do something to prevent it. What **specific** problem are you having?

Comment: I have modified the question, I am trying multiple async operation in a loop, i want to terminate the script when all the async operations are completed..

Comment: Does db.collection.remove return a promise? Await will only work with functions that return promises.

Comment: No, i will try with returning with a promise

Comment: If I understand the mongo docs correctly, remove is not an asynchronous operation, so in your case, you don't need async/await. Try if your code works if you remove it

Comment: I think, its an async operation, but I may be wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said that `db.collection(...).remove(...)` doesn't return a promise, but that you'll try one. Once you do:

`forEach` doesn't do anything with the return value of the callback, so it won't do anything to wait for the promises created by your `async` callback to settle.

Instead, to run them in **parallel**, use `map` and `Promise.all`:

```
await Promise.all(mobile_numbers.map(number => {
    return /*...create a promise for the remove operation here...*/;
}));
```

Example:

```js
const removeNumber = number => new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log(`Removing ${number}...`);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`${number} removed`);
    resolve();
  }, Math.random() * 500);
});

async function deletor(mobile_numbers) {
    await Promise.all(mobile_numbers.map(number => {
        return removeNumber(number);
    }));
}

deletor(["111", "222", "333", "444", "555"])
    .then(() => { console.log("Done"); })
    .catch(err => { console.error("Error:", err); });
```

To run them in series, you can use the "Promise reduce" trick:

```
await mobile_numbers.reduce((p, number) => {
    return p.then(() => {
        return /*...create a promise for the remove operation here...*/
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Example:

```js
const removeNumber = number => new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log(`Removing ${number}...`);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`${number} removed`);
    resolve();
  }, Math.random() * 200);
});

async function deletor(mobile_numbers) {
    await mobile_numbers.reduce((p, number) => {
        return p.then(() => {
            return removeNumber(number);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
}

deletor(["111", "222", "333", "444", "555"])
    .then(() => { console.log("Done"); })
    .catch(err => { console.error("Error:", err); });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, this code really worked!.  you were right "forEach doesn't do anything with the return value of the callback, so it won't do anything to wait for the promises created by your async callback to settlel"

Answer (score 1):

1) Try this code

```
deletor().then(() => process.exit(0));
```

Async function “deletor()” returns a promise. That means you can use a method “then()” executed after “deletor()”.

Another way is using async “main()” function

```
async function deletor() {...}
async function main() {
    await deletor();
    process.exit(0);
 }
 main();
```

2) Instead of “.forEach(async ...)” you should use either

```
Promise.all(...)
```

or

```
for (const item of items) {
   await .....
}
```

First case runs parallel. Second runs serial.